# How do I remove the previous App Store user from my computer?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Someone else at the office was attempting to help me setup the laptop before I started, so now my MBP has their credentials for some apps. I can uninstall and reinstall the app, if that's all it takes, but how do I remove this user from the system so it quites prompting me?

[image: Image showing me updating App Store apps and it prompting me to use another account]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The App Store app uses spotlight to find all the apps on your Mac that were downloaded from the store. You need to run a search and delete all those apps from the Mac (your personal data and settings do not get deleted) and re-download the app. Remember, you could have more than one copy of an app, so keep checking until they all are deleted.

Step one of course, it to sign out from the other account if you haven't done that yet. When the App Store App is running, choose the **Store -> Sign Out** menu item.

The details on how the App Store app actually knows if an app was downloaded is buried inside the application bundle as descrtibed on this quesiton about avoiding updates to apps entirely.

- [How can I opt out of updates for one app when using the App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69821/how-can-i-change-an-app-purchased-from-the-app-store-so-that-i-dont-get-updates)

Answer (score -3):

Try to change account into System Settings -> iCloud.

(duplicate of [Being asked to log into a different account on Mac App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60018/being-asked-to-log-into-a-different-account-on-mac-app-store?rq=1))

Comment: I'm the only one logged into iCloud as far as I can tell? I mean, nobody was there, then I logged in like two weeks ago. I would've noticed if someone were logged in there.

Comment: The iCloud settings have nothing to do with clearing an App Store account. I suppose it might be where the initial setup happened, but you'll have to go elsewhere to fix this issue. See my answer for details.